# Best VCS and hosting for a student group of 10?

Tags: git, version-control, project-management, assembla

We are a student group consisting of ten people. For the next few months, we need to work on a big project together. Therefore, we thought it would be better if we use a VCS.

Many people in the group use git, but we need a web hosting that provides private repository and collaboration. As far as I know bitbucket provides free private repositories, but I wanted to ask if we have better alternatives.

It does not have to be git. We are open to learning new things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am the CTO at Assembla**

You should definitely use a VCS, your life and code will be that much better and easier to work in. That being said, [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) is a hosted VCS system for Project Management.

Assembla offers a free offering for small groups, however if this is a Student project, we are open to offering a very large offering for free to students for private or public use.  Just contact me and I will set you up (goes for anyone with a .edu email address, later this process will be formalized and available on the site)

Assembla has lots to offer for project management and repositories, as well, it is fast to start and get using. We offer subversion, git, perforce, and hg repositories integrated with various tools including a ticketing and issue tracking tool.

Take a look at our [blog](http://blog.assembla.com), specifically these posts:

[Looking for a Git Bug Tracker](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/98335/Looking-for-a-Git-Bug-Tracker-Look-No-More.aspx)

[Devlop Faster: Setup Your Git Fork and Merge Network](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/96552/Develop-Faster-Set-Up-Your-Git-Fork-and-Merge-Network.aspx)

Comment: Well, actually we already completed the project successfully. The funny thing is we decided to use Assembla and SVN for the project and it helped us a lot.

Here, I would like to thank you for the great product :)

Comment: That is great to hear, feel free to contact me anytime if you need any help, etc.